# Creating Legends in a tkinter frame

Tags: python, tkinter

[tkinter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4J2r.png)

[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIzem.png)

I am a bit struggling with tkinter Labels. I have created my GUI with tkinter frames and instead of packing I used grids as it is the most convenient thing. My problem is, in my 'tkinter picture' I want to create legends in the mentioned 'label container' area and that should have the legends like in the highlighted area from demo picture. I followed some examples using canvas and then had to pack it. I tried to use grid system instead but nothing came out and used canvas methods like create_text, create_Line.  Can someone help me in this regard.

## creating labels to top_left_frame_left_label_container

```
# ========================================================================================
def creating_labels(self):
    self.canvas = Canvas(self.top_left_frame_left_label_container)
    self.canvas.grid()
    # self.canvas.create_line(0, 0, 20, 20, fill='green', width=2, tags='line1')
    self.legend_frame = LabelFrame(self.canvas, text='Legend', padx=5, pady=5)
    self.legendLabel = Label(self.legend_frame, text = 'Hi')
    self.legendLabel.pack()
```

That is just an example, can't think to have the right approach.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to `place` the Label instead?

Comment: @HenryYik Exactly, I can place label and I can even divide the frame into a grid of 5*2(5 rows and 2 columns) and in one column I can create a line by using canvas_createLine and in the second column I can add text with canvas.createText but it is very static and then it will contain many lines of code as you can't pack a grid inside frame then I have to configure rows and columns each of them seperately.